# atomic blocks in Java for matched data

Tags: java, synchronization, atomic

A library I'm writing has a class implementing a two dimensional map and also provides, for efficient reading, smaller maps for the row/column views.  So far all methods have been overridden so that any change in the main map are mirrored in the sub maps and vice versa.  The problem comes in concurrent operation.

Ideally a removal of an item from the master map will simultaneously remove the item from the respective row and column maps, but this is of course impossible.  For example in my put function:

```
public synchronized Cell put(Duple<Integer, Integer> key, Cell arg1){
    //preprocessing, detecting the row/col, creating row/col if not present yet, etc.
    Cell outcell = super.put(key, arg1);
    rowArr.putPriv(key.getElem2(), arg1);
    colArr.putPriv(key.getElem1(), arg1);
    arg1.assignCell(this, key);
    return outCell;
}
```

While it is perfectly acceptable for simultaneous reads of the map and even concurrent modification is not an issue (except for the creation/removal of rows/columns which needs remove and put to be synchronized), but The 4 stages of modification (super.put, the row and column puts, and the cell location update) need to be atomic to ensure it's not possible to read unmatched data.

What are my options?  As far as I've found from my searching it's not possible to create an atomic sequence of statements in Java, and synchronisation isn't going to work unless I synchronise all my functions (which prevents concurrent reads, and I would need locks on multiple items).  I know the principles of (but am not particularly practiced in) basic semaphore concepts, but don't see any simple ways to make a lock-on-write semaphore without massive complexity, particularly if I don't want to have massive waits for a writing slot.  What additional options do I have?

Note: due to the project I'm on I cannot use derivative languages such as groovy but can only use standard Java 1.6u24, without 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you not synchronize on entire method `put`. But **synchronize only on on specific cell**. In code below, I'll describe how to do that:

```
class ConcurrMattr {

    private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Lock> locks = 
                    new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Lock>();

    public Cell put( CellCoords key, Cell arg1 ) {
        // get or create lock for specific cell (guarantee its uniqueness)
        Lock lock = this.locks.putIfAbsent( coords.hash % 64, new ReentrantLock() );
        // 64 threads may concurrently modify different cells of matrix

        try {
            // lock only specific cell
            lock.lock();

            // do all you need with cell

            return ...;

        } finally {
            // unlock cell
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }    
}


// Immutable class to represent cell coordinates
class CellCoords {    
    public final int x;
    public final int y;
    public final int hash;

    public CellCoords( int x, int y ) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.hash = this.calcHash();
    }

    private int calcHash() {
        int result = 31 + this.x;
        return 31 * result + this.y;
    }
}
```

So you may synchronize `read/write` methods on specific cell, while **other part of matrix will be accessible to other threads**.

Look at javadoc for [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) and for [`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html)

**P.S.** 
You may notice, that `CellCoords` field `hash` has type `int`. To avoid growth of locks map size till 2^31, you have to **limit range of hashes**. For example: `(coords.hash % 64)` - allows only 64 concurrent threads to work with entire matrix.

P.P.S. Might be interesting article for you: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp08223/

Comment: Reading around a little I saw the interface for ReadWriteLock.  This may be the exact solution I'm looking for!  It does mean I need locks in my get functions, but at least they are clean and concurrent.

Comment: @K.Barad, you may use read and write locks separately, only if you can guarantee that there won't be a race condition: when one thread write data, and other thread read data from the same cell. Otherwise read-thread can get inconsistent data

Comment: from what I read the ReadWriteLock allows multiple read locks to be acquired, but the write lock is exclusive.  While the write lock is held no one else can read, meaning that the write and read locks are in a master-slave style relationship.  To me this sounds like the perfect behaviour to achieve what I want unless you see further risks?  I will have the write lock all going through the put and remove functions anyway so 90% of the work happens outside the locks, only the 4 modification lines are synched.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your row/column views dynamically when the relevant methods are called. That way, you rid yourself of the four-way update that's causing your issues.

(You'll be trading simplicity for decreased efficiency, but that might not be a problem if you're not in a high-performance environment. And even then, it would be worth benchmarking the solutions to see if it really is a bad move).

Comment: Interesting idea, but the issue then would be that the row/column maps are out of date very quickly.  The idea is that depending on the usage it would be valuable to pick off a row and spend some time working with it, much like taking a record from a database.  Ok, granted half the uses planned for this library will be single thread, but if it's going to be a library it needs to be robust.

Comment: I would assume you'd be cloning the maps before returning them to the user though? In which case, yes they are dated from the moment you clone them. If not, then surely you have a major thread safety issue if every caller gets their hands on your map?

Comment: Thread safety is one of the reasons why I'm asking.  While I understand the theory I don't naturally think in concurrent ways and so I've not got the experience in coding it.  Stemm's answer with the locks may have led to the system I'm looking for though.